# How to use a UIActionSheet to confirm deletion of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uiactionsheet

I have a standard CoreData/NSFetchedResultsController/UITableView setup.  There is no edit button on top, but right-swiping a row will reveal the delete button.  If the delete button pressed, I want to pop up a UIActionSheet to confirm the deletion.

Before the UIActionSheet, I just implemented `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` and in it, I called `deleteObject:` on the managedObjectContext for the indexPath and let the FetchedResultsController overrides handle the visual aspect of it.

Now, I have `tableView:commitEditingStyoe:forRowAtIndexPath:` create the UIActionSheet and show it.  I implemented `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` and put the `deleteObject:` in the case where the delete button is pressed.  The problem is that I need the indexPath of the item to delete and it is no longer in scope.

Do I...

A) delete the ManagedObject in `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` and either save or roll back in `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` ?

B) store the index path as a property so I can set it in `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` and read it in `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:`?

C) something else...

Option A seems like more overhead than necessary.  Either way it will be deleted, just sometimes it will be rolled back.

Option B seems very hawkish.  An external value like that doesn't seem to fit the object oriented model very well.

Is there a generic object in UIActionsSheet for passing in values like this?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I needed a similar solution.  I solved this by creating an ivar `NSIndexPath * currentPath;`  and used the following idea for `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView     * alert;
    UITableViewCell * cell;
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // save current indexPath
        [currentPath release];
        currentPath = [indexPath retain];

        // display warning
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Really?"
                message:@"Are you really really sure you want to delete this item?"
                delegate:self
                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        // clear delete confirmation from table view cell
        cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [cell setEditing:YES animated:YES];
     };
     return;
  }
```

If the user taps the delete button, I then remove the row from the UITableViewCell and remove the entry from the data source.  If they tap cancel, I simply ignore the action.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the indexPath I would store the managed object itself in a property in the `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath`: method:

```
self.deleteCandidate = [self.controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

and then delete that object (or not) in `-actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:`, and set `self.deleteCandidate = nil` in either case.

The reason is that the fetched results controller objects might change between those two methods being called.

Another option is to use "Associative References" (objc_setAssociatedObject, objc_getAssociatedObject) to store a reference from the UIActionSheet to the object in question.